# File Name Extract From String works every other time

Tags: excel, vba, extract

I need help understanding why file name extraction from string only works every other time.

I've tried both right and mid.  I've used before in other code with no problem.  I'm useing msgbox for debugging.

Final outcome should be adding multiple file names to the bottom of a table

```
Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim fName As String ' full path file name
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim filename As String ' extracted file name only

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.Title = "Please select file to add"
    fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fchosen = fd.Show

    If fchosen = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            fName = fd.SelectedItems(i)
            
            'filename = Right(fName, Len(fName) - InStrRev(filename, "\"))
            filename = Mid(fName, InStrRev(filename, "\") + 1)
            
            MsgBox (filename)
            nextRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            'Range("a" & nextRow) = filename
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Should this line `filename = Mid(fName, InStrRev(filename, "\") + 1)` actually be `filename = Mid(fName, InStrRev(fName, "\") + 1)`? At that point in your code, `filename` doesn't have a value yet, so the `InStrRev` would always return `0`

Comment: @JoshEller - that did the trick.  thank you.

Comment: @kosta-k I was trying them both and they both had same problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Josh writes in the comments, you are using the wrong variable `filename` instead of `fname`. Another example of how nesting commands makes it difficult to find an error and how naming of variables matters.

Split the lines into two pieces and rename `fname` to something like `fullFilename`:

```
Dim fullFilename as string, filename as string, p as long
fullFilename = fd.SelectedItems(i)
p = InStrRev(fullFilename, "\")
if p > 0 then
    filename = mid(fullFilename, p+1)
else
    filename = fullFilename
End If
```

Now you can easily distinguish between the variable holding the full path and the one that has only the file name. And even if you mix something up, you can easily find the problem using the debugger

Comment: thank you.  josh's comment above did the trick.

Comment: Sure it did (and I wrote that). I just wanted to show how you can avoid such errors in future.

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas.  I haven't used splitting as much, but as I review what you did, I can see advantages, especially in longer code when referencing similar function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick

**Get File Name From File Path**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    MsgBox GetFilenameFromPath("C:\Temp\Myfile.Txt")
End Sub

Private Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath( _
        Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

**Get File Name Without Extension**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim fName As String
    fName = "C:\Temp\Myfile.Txt"
    
    MsgBox GetFilenameFromPath(Left(fName, (InStrRev(fName, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)))
End Sub

Private Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath( _
        Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: thank you.  josh's comment above did the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  It will take me a little time to digest your code to understand what the $ does.

Comment: I found $ denotes string.  It's a different approach.  I like the idea of creating function I can refer to in other macros.